# CSS attribute selector with empty brackets `[]`

Tags: css

I noticed that `[]` is a valid CSS selector, but does it do something?

I can't manage to match anything with it.

Or is it just a syntactic remanent that remains valid but can't be used?

Thanks.

Comment: It's attribute selector. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: As an empty attribute selector `[]` no, I can't imagine it would be used to select anything. It needs the name of an attribute to do anything, so leaving it empty would be like saying, select the element that has a non-existent attribute, which isn't a thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can with some "invisible" cheating. Edit the snippet to notice the trick.

```css
[​] {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div ​></div>
```

Comment: Interesting ... but this is not really an empty attribute selector, it just appears empty.

Comment: Let us call it `the white-space selector`.  Does -- not -- work here: https://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/9r2g4abx/1/ .

Comment: @deEr. as I said it's invisible. You need to do a copy/paste not type it yourself because you missed the important part

Comment: For some background, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space